# Wait for an Axios call to finish in Quasar / Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a function in a Quasar application that needs to call an Web API that I need to wait until I get the results back to call the next function. I've posted my code and I'm sure that I'm missing some await or async or have them in the wrong place.

```
  Global ex='';   

  testFunction3(arg){
   console.log(arg)
  } , 

  testFunction2(){  
  this.ex = update_Members_data_term("@musc.edu");
  },

  async  testFunction(){  
  await this.testFunction2()

  this.testFunction3(this.ex)
 },
```

API call:

```
function update_Members_data_term(term) {
 axios.get(
    'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi', {
        params: {
            db: 'pubmed',
            api_key: '',
            retmode: 'json',
            retmax: 200,
            term: term
        }
    }
).then(async response => {
    return response.data.esearchresult.idlist;      
}).catch(error => {
    console.log(error.response)
})
```

}

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

`testFunction2` Doesn't return a `Promise` so `await` does nothing. You are actually doing `await null;`

So the fix will be:

```
function update_Members_data_term(term) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        axios.get(
            'https://eutils.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/entrez/eutils/esearch.fcgi', {
            params: {
                db: 'pubmed',
                api_key: '',
                retmode: 'json',
                retmax: 200,
                term: term
            }
        }
        ).then(async response => {
            resolve(response.data.esearchresult.idlist);
        }).catch(error => {
            reject(error.response)
        })
    });
}

async testFunction2(){  
this.ex = await update_Members_data_term("email_here");
},
```

- Note that you might just `await axios.get` instead of returning a Promise, but I'm not sure what the syntax is.

Comment: We don't need the extra promise. You can chain .then as then returns itself a new promise: `.then(...).then(...).then(...)`

So `await update_Members_data_term("silvestr@musc.edu");` should suffice.